# Получение  значений из значений Яндекс бара.

Tags: c

Здравствуйте!

Пишу консольную программу на СИ, ни как не могу понять алгоритм и код. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне отсюда

http://bar-navig.yandex.ru/u?show=31&url=http://yandex.ru

Получить значение **value=**
Никак не могу понять, буду благодарен если подскажете.
То есть программа должна сама подставить домен и вывести это значение.

Благодарю!

Comment: Я что-то не понял. У Вас есть этот XML документ, и нужно из него считать значение параметра value? Или еще что-то?

Comment: Самой программе нежно зайти на сайт по этому адресу:
http://bar-navig.yandex.ru/u?show=31&url=http://(здесь я из переменной подставляю домен).
И на этой странице взять значение value и вернуть мне его.
Я ясно написал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самых общих чертах. Для начала надо скачать этот документ используя либо чистые сокеты, либо какую-то обертку.
Потом его пропарсить. Если известен номер строки, то закачиваете ее в буфер, далее с помощью функции strstr находите вход подстроки "value=", далее по найденному указателю находите то, что идет вслед за этим словом, т.е. значение параметра.